# Is it possible to work with GSP (groovy server pages) without the whole grails stuff?

Tags: grails, groovy, installation, gsp

I'd just like to play a little bit with groovy

I was thinking about developing my own-tiny web framework, something very simple and manageable...

So i'd like tou use GSP pages whtout having to install the whole grails stuff, with all its dependencies and behind-the-scenes frameworks...

can anyone provide me detailed instructions on what to download, where to install, how to configure tomcat, etc...

---

some info I've found so far

> [Groovy Servlets](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets)
>
> [GSP Tag Reference](http://www.grails.org/GSP+Tag+Reference)

this is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but still don't know what to download, where to save it, etc...

> http://groovy.codehaus.org/GSP

And look what it says here...

> GSP are not maintained as a standalone module. But it has been forked and reintegrated in Grails.

?

Comment: I want to "refresh" this question a.d. 2015 (Groovy 2.4). Few years ago I had a short but good experience with non-Grails GSP (groovy 1.7-1.8).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it seems like it wasn't so hard in deed as I expected

just had to copy groovy-all-1.5.7.jar

from C:\java\groovy-1.5.7\embeddable

to C:\java\Tomcat 6.0\lib

and add the following lines to C:\java\Tomcat 6.0\conf\web.xml

```
  <!-- Groovy mapping - sas 2009-01-29 -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Groovy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Groovy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GroovyTemplate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet</servlet-class>    
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GroovyTemplate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and it worked!!!

I haven't even downloaded the grails installer...

could it really be that easy???

here are some links

http://noor.ojuba.org/2008/06/groovlets-setting-up/

Comment: Only thing I would add is that I would recommend that you put the groovy jars in the your-webapp/WEB-INF/lib if possible, this will simplify deployment and remove the chance of conflicts with other apps using groovy

Comment: Its old, but see this sample app which shows how to use gsp without grails
https://github.com/grails/grails-boot/tree/master/sample-apps/gsp

Comment: This is what I'm doing as well, but note that TemplateServlet gives you `${...}` and `<% ... %>`, but not tags such as `<g:if>`. Those would make a substantial difference in readability, not to mention supporting custom taglibs.

Answer (score 4):

Standalone GSP is on the current Grails roadmap. In the mean time see the GSP module project page: https://gsp.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 3):

This JavaWorld article might lend a hand:

[Shed the weight with Groovlets](http://www.javaworld.com/community/?q=node/2292)

> Not all web applications require a full stack framework (like Grails, Rails, Spring MVC, etc). Don’t get me wrong, the aforementioned hip frameworks are themselves lightweight (and quite powerful to boot); however, they do have an associated cost (albeit much much lower than rolling the same functionality by hand). For instance, some applications don’t require a data store (consequently, a large portion of Grails — that is, Hibernate — for example, wouldn’t be utilized). Other applications don’t really require a powerful view technology (simple services don’t require JSPs or GSPs, for instance).

Comment: that link has moved on to https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072589/shed-the-weight-with-groovlets.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Rabbtor](http://knowledgebase.rabbytes.com/display/rabbtordoc). We provide easy GSP integration to Spring MVC applications with customizations to Grails' tag libraries. Most common tag libraries are supported but some Grails dependent ones were removed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the taglib functionality is in the Groovlet stuff.